# Should an employer force workers to use particular software?

Tags: software

Let's say that a company has made years of Word documents or Excel spreadsheets in Windows but one day there is a new worker who is more familiar with say LaTeX, Open Office and Linux. Should the boss force a new employer to use the programs everyone else uses? In my opinion, worker should use the software he or she can use the most smoothly but are there other opinions?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace.  This is not a discussion forum but a Q&A site focused on answerable questions.  This sounds like you want to start a discussion, so I'm putting it on hold.  Please check out the [tour] and the link in the notice above, and then see if you can rewrite the question to fit here better.  If you [edit] it, it will be put into a review queue for reopening.  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to get fired, use the software you want. Honestly, if others need your documents and tehy are not in the correct program then they are messed up by your screw-up in using something not authorized. There are also licensing issues, etc. Be a grown-up and use what the company uses. This is not playtime where you can do what you want. This is work.

Comment: My old company standardizes on Open Source as much as possible.We learned the hard way that OpenOffice and MS Office are NOT 100% compatible. Needless to say, the documents we get from suppliers, vendors, customers, business partners are all in MS Office. So we HAVE to have MS Office. If you produce a key doc in Open Office that renders like garbage on a customer's MS Office, we'll be looking for you. If you use LATEX and the customer has to figure out how to render in MS Office, you will be subjected to a very unpleasant internal meeting, or we'll just decide that we don't want to keep you.

Comment: Your question clearly indicates that you have given no thought to coordination, team work and interacting with other parties. Ask such a question when you are interviewing with me and your job candidacy is done. You arenot fit to work with others if you give NO consideration of the impact of  what you do and how you do it on others.

Comment: @HLGEM, there is nothing wrong with someone using whatever they want within reason. The issue is really how this person will inter-operate with others. Obviously, one can't slip a latex file into a deliverable if everyone else uses word. But, in all but the most draconian places there is some latitude in what people can install and use on their machines within their own cube. Moreover, most IT departments can't realistically specify everything and lock it all down. This is how countless software vendors gain a foothold with new corporate customers.

Comment: @teego1967 they certainly can. Any extra software package can cause IT more work because sooner or later they'll have to support it by answering questions or getting to play happily with the standard app in use.

Comment: I have never worked anywhere where other software was acceptable if a standard pacakage was provided by the company. Ever - in over 30 years. I would fire anyone who use a unix based piece of software on my Windows development enviroment withouth prior approval.

Comment: @HLGEM... like I said, it is all about inter-operating with others. Obvisouly, it would be bad judgment to randomly inject unapproved tools/software/formats into other people's workflow. But would you "fire" someone who used "Notepad++" instead of "Notepad" on their PC?

Comment: If I had a corporate standard, yes. All software must be approved in advance in many environments and I work in one of them.  So yes it would be a firing offense because he was not following the corporate policy. These are not your personal machines - they belong to the company, you do not ever have the right to put what you want on them.  You don't own them. What part of not my property, the owner of the property has the right to decide what goes on it do you not understand?

Comment: @HLGEM, so sorry to hear that you work in such a severe environment. Workplaces vary quite a bit in what is permissible and different workers need different latitude, moreover "corporate policy" is in many cases too dumb and slow to be able to dictate every little tool/package/application for every worker. It is sad to see that there are places where individual judgment is categorically dismissed in favor of rigid "policy".

Comment: I don't believe this question is "primarily opinion-based", as demonstrated by Julia Hayward's excellent (and not primarily opinion-based) answer. Certainly I feel that this question is debatable enough that it should not have been closed by moderator fiat without 5 close votes.

Comment: @teego1967 Of course workplaces vary. Everywhere I've been, there's been a certain amount of latitude - because they have been small to micro- companies where I'm accepted as an expert and we all have a great deal of trust in each other. That doesn't translate to a company of thousands where for every expert there are tens of schmucks who *believe* they know what they are doing and will blunder into installing games, pirated stuff or malware unless all machines are locked down. In such a shop the only workable strategy is simply - don't do it **without higher authorisation**

Comment: @JuliaHayward, not sure what you're saying. Obviously if the computers are locked down to the point where one can't install anything, higher authorization is required and there is clearly no question of "being allowed". I am talking about professional workplaces with knowledge workers who more often than not have the latitude to use judgement on tool-choice. The caveat is that they _must_ be able to interoperate with others. This doesn't just apply to small companies, it can apply to individual workgroups within large companies.

Comment: @teego, it is actually a great place to work. If using whatever you want is more important to you than doing interesting work, then I feel sorry for you.  It doesn't matter if corporate policy is not what you want, you have to learn to work within the constraints you have as all jobs ultimately have constraints. Companies without them tend to fail rather regularly. There are valuid reasons for many coprporate policies, you just need to look outside your little box and see them.

Comment: @HLGEM, there is a HUGE space between "using whatever you want" and working in an environment where every little thing is specified to the point where one needs a permission slip to use _any_ tool that has not been provided by the company.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"worker should use the software he or she can use the most smoothly"

No. Employees should use the software that makes the business as a whole function most effectively. Reasons an employee should not have his own personal choice include:

- Licensing. The company may already have licences for product A, and not wish to spend on product B. Alternatively they may have exclusivity agreements with suppliers.
- Document compatibility. Product B is useless if it produces anything that is not guaranteed compatible with Product A.
- Extra work for IT staff to be familiar with and maintain two products.
- Setting precedents - one employee might be fine to leave with product B, but it gives co-workers a green flag to install whatever they choose.

If you don't like what your company uses, by all means produce a business case for changing. Even then you still have to accept that higher management may see issues that you can't see from your position.